# Adding newly created layer to Map in CURRENT project using ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro, valueerror

In this script, I create a feature layer from a file geodatabase feature class and wish to add the layer into a map within the current session in ArcGIS Pro 2.0.  The script crashes on the last line.  How do I fix this error?

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("MainMap")[0] 
featureLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(splitSegmentFC, "SegmentSplit")  
aprxMap.addLayer(featureLayer)
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\ProvingGrounds\SCAT\Script\ArcGISpro\ScatTrackProcessing_v10_PRO.py", line 1520, in <module>
aprxMap.addLayer(featureLayer)
File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 191, in fn_
return fn(*args, **kw)
File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1055, in addLayer
return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.addLayer(*gp_fixargs((add_layer_or_layerfile, add_position), True)))
ValueError: SegmentSplit
Failed to execute (Script).
```

Comment: The error seems to come from line 1520 of your code. What happens when you run only the code snippet that you have presented?

Comment: @PolyGeo - I think I found the problem.  Arcpy 3.5 appears to require that there be a zero index [0] at the end of the Make Feature Layer function if I am assigning it as an object. Do you know why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `featureLayer` to a result object.

Try this instead:

```
splitSegmentFC = r"path_to_your_feature_class"
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("MainMap")[0]
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(splitSegmentFC, "SegmentSplit")
```

You should see the layer added to your MainMap map.

Comment: This obviously works when using the Python window in ArcGIS Pro, but I am having trouble adding a layer to the map using a script (run from with a toolbox). Should i be using something like  
    aprxMap.addLayer

Comment: @Nic In a new question, what is the code snippet that you want to ask about?