# Adding feature class to Map in CURRENT project using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro

I want to add a feature class within a Geodatabase to a map in ArcGIS Pro (1.4.1) using ArcPy. I am converting some python code from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro.

This issue is very similar to:

- [Adding newly created layer to Map in CURRENT project using ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249931) and
- [Adding feature class to map (within specific group) using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260114)

However, instead of adding a feature class (or layer) to a map using the Python Window I am doing this from a  Script within a Toolbox. I have included a code snippet below.

```
lyrTest = r"C:\data\test.gdb\Layer1" 
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("MainMap")[0] 
lyrFile = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(lyrTest)
aprxMap.addLayer(lyrFile)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\data\AddLayers.py", line 5, in <module>    
aprxMap.addLayer(lyrTest)
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 191, in fn_
return fn(*args, **kw)
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1048, in addLayer
return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.addLayer(*gp_fixargs((add_layer_or_layerfile, add_position), True)))
ValueError: C:\data\test.gdb\Layer1
Failed to execute (AddLayers).
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `addDataFromPath` method on the Map object worked for me, as shown in code below.

```
lyrTest = r"C:\data\test.gdb\Layer1" 
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("MainMap")[0] 
aprxMap.addDataFromPath(lyrTest)
```

and if you also need a Layer object from that data then change the last line to:

```
lyr = aprxMap.addDataFromPath(lyrTest)
```

See the [ArcGIS Pro Help for Map class properties](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm#M2_GUID-CD5119D8-1DD8-46A3-9051-3DFE58C6B5A6):

> The addDataFromPath method provides a way to add a layer to a map in a
>   similar way to how the **Add Data From Path** button works in the
>   application; it places each layer based on layer weight rules and
>   geometry type. For more precise layer placement control, refer to the
>   moveLayer method.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the function/method is expecting a layerFile (.lyr or .lyrx)  and you are providing it was a feature class (which some colloquially refer to as a layer to add to the confusion).

I believe your issue is that you are trying to *add* a layer file when you should be creating one and then adding it. if you do something like below it should work with your current set up.

```
aprxMap = map.listMaps()[0]    
file = mp.LayerFile("C:\Temp\deleteme.lyrx")
aprxMap.addLayer(file)
```

Otherwise you should use [`MakeFeatureLayer`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm)  like below to add a Feature Class as a feature Layer and name it `"PickMeAsTheAnswer"`

`arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyrTest,"PickMeAsTheAnswer")`