# Seeking syntax for arcpy.mapping.Layer() in ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm working on a project where I am porting Python Tools created for ArcMap Desktop into ArcMap Pro but I am encountering an issue when I get to lines of the original code that read:

`insertLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(input)`, which aims to create a `Layer` object to manipulate/process.

Having presumed product compatibility, I tried `insertLayer = arcpy.mp.Layer(input)` but that didn't work - I get the error message **module 'arcpy.mp' has no attribute 'Layer'**

From the help pages, I can see there are two ways to access `Layer` object:

1. Using `listLayers` method of `Map` object, which is dependent on an
   existing project file (.aprx) with the map having the target layer
2. Using `MakeFeatureLayer_management`, which creates a Layer from a feature class and let you to use of a string (i.e., the second argument) in place of a layer object but its use is generally limited to *Select from Layer* operations.

What is the best way to port the `Layer` object, which is created in ArcGIS Desktop, to Pro?

Comment: What does your code leading up to where you are stuck look like?  At the moment the code you have presented looks like a line copy/pasted from somewhere else and would not qualify as a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @BravoZulu I would recommend checking out the [Migrating from arcpy.mapping](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm) page in the Help. The flow chart might be particularly useful. It also says: `Layer management functions have moved

The stand-alone layer management functions are now methods on the Map and LayerFile objects. The methods include addLayer, addLayerToGroup, insertLayer, moveLayer, and removeLayer`

Comment: @PolyGeo, I think this is an important matter, since I use arcpy.mapping.Layer class to create `Layer` objects and find it quite convenient, i.e., I can create a temporary layer by `lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'C:\Temp\test.shp')` and use it to access its properties, say `lyr.visible` or `lyr.definitionQuery`. However, the only ways to create a layer object in arcgis-pro either `MakeFeatureLayer_management` or `listLayers` method of `Map` object. The former lets use of a string in place of layer object (I find it quite stupid) and the others cannot be accessed directly from feature class.

Comment: When it comes to portability, lets say a line in the old script to assign a definition query to a layer created by `arcpy.mapping.Layer` can be easily done if you have Layer object, e.g.,`lyr.definitionQuery = "Desc = 'IT IS QUITE EASY'"`. However, `"outputLyr".definitionQuery` will yield an error or you need to first save the `MakeFeatureLayer_management` result as `lyrx` and then create a layer as I desire by `arcpy.mp.LayerFile('BLA')`.

Comment: @fatih_dur I've done a lot with this part of arcpy.mp and so I think all that needs to be done is for someone to improve the code snippet to illustrate what has been tried and where they are stuck. You could edit to do that. If there is a second issue then a second question with a new code snippet should be asked.

Comment: @BravoZulu, can you please check my edits and confirm if it (still) reflects your problem?

Comment: I think this still needs a code snippet showing why  listLayers does not work for you I.e. not just a line or two of code but something that works up to where you are stuck. cc @fatih_dur

Comment: For example, what is `input` set to in your `arcpy.mapping` code?

Comment: I have a suspicion that this may be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/265592/115 but without a more detailed code snippet here, I am not certain.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I see your point and think I did a fair bit of editing on the question, which may not be even appropriate. My main problem is how to create the Layer object from a feature class during the run-time, independent from .aprx or .lyrx. I did use this technique almost all the time and seeing this discontinued is frustrating.

Comment: @fatih_dur Not sure if I have ever tested but http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm says `lyr = mapx.addDataFromPath(data_path)` should give you the Layer object that you seek.

Comment: @BravoZulu I'm having this same issue, did you ever find a means of creating a Layer object from a featureclass path using pro?