# Adding results from geoprocessing scripts to ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro

I am in the process of updating scripts and models from ArcGIS Desktop to work in Pro however I'm having difficulty getting results from geoprocessing operations to display in the map window.

As an example, for the following snippet:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwiteOutput = True
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("*")[0]
inputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outputWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
outputFC = outputWorkspace + "\\" + outputFC
arcpy.MultipartToSinglepart_management(inputFC, outputFC)
outputLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outputFC, "outputLyr")
m.addLayer(outputLyr, "TOP")
```

I get the error: "ValueError: outputLyr". The process completes successfully, it's just that I can't get the result to add to the map.

My knowledge of python is quite limited but as I understand it, a feature class needs to be made into a layer before being added to the map. Previously in Desktop we used the following:

```
layer_file = arcpy.mapping.Layer(outputFC)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataframe, layer_file)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try putting `outputLyr` in quotation marks, `m.addLayer("outputLyr", "TOP")`

Comment: To compliment @fatih_dur, `outputLyr` is a Result object, all geo-processing tools return Result objects which you can then query to get the actual result. Search the help file on Result objects. So one would say you have used poor coding standards you called your result object the same as your layer name, ripe for confusion!

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but am getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Interestingly it looks like I can get around it by directly adding the output FC using m.addDataFromPath(outputFC) instead as per this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265592/add-feature-class-to-current-map-using-arcpy-in-arcgis-pro?rq=1), though I'd prefer to try and get MakeFeatureLayer_management to work instead.