# arcpy.mp.LayerFile() OSError

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layer-file

I'm new to GIS programming, and am going through the Esri ["Getting Started with arcpy.mp" tutorial](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/tutorial-getting-started-with-arcpy-mp.htm).

When I try the following:

```
lyrFile = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(r"path to a layer file")
```

I get the following error:

> File "", line 1, in 
>     File "c:\users\ME\appdata\local\programs\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy_mp.py", line 773, in **init**
>       self._arc_object = arcgisscripting._mapping.LayerFile(*gp_fixargs((layer_file_path,), True))
>   OSError: C:\Users\ME\Documents\ArcGIS\myLayer.lyrx

Typical google search doesn't really bring up much except for [Adding feature class to Map in CURRENT project using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265592)

I've tried the alternate methods of adding a Layer file as suggested in the question thread, but get the same OS error.

What is causing this error, so I can figure out how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro? lyrx is a ArcGIS Pro layer file

Comment: Yep, just discovered my error!  Doing tutorial in Pro, trying to use layer created in Desktop 10.5 which has a '.lyr' extension, not '.lyrx'

Comment: I save as the .lyrx layer in ArcPro but still get the same error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149921)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149921)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149921)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to pay attention to file extensions!

The tutorial assumes you created the layer file in ArcGIS Pro.  I was attempting to add a layer created in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5, which has the '.lyr' extension, NOT '.lyrx'.

Comment: For those whom this answer did not suffice, be sure to check something as simple as whether you spelled the name of the layer file correctly, or whether the file path is correct! `OSError` comes up with something related to the system, not `arcpy`.