# Adding feature class to active map from geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers

An extension of the question answered here:

[Adding feature class to Map in CURRENT project using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265592/adding-feature-class-to-map-in-current-project-using-arcpy-in-arcgis-pro)

This method adds the feature class to the first map in the project, but what if I wanted to add it to the active map?

Comment: Have you looked for a property on the ArcGISProject class?

Comment: Can you complement your link to a question with code to the actual code as formatted text within your question to help illustrate where you are stuck, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.activeMap
```